# Alternate for left join

Tags: sql, oracle

```
/*Tables:*/
SELECT tid, SID FROM t_s_map;/*student id whom teacher has access*/
SELECT sgid FROM sg;/* student_group table*/
SELECT sgid, SID FROM sgm;/*student group members table(info of students under student group)*/
/*Note: All columns are id and have values > 0*/
```

Sample data:

```
Table: sg
sgid
101
201

Table: sgm  
sgid    sid
101     1
101     2
101     3
201     1
201     2

Table: t_s_map  
tid sid
11  1
11  2
11  3
22  1
22  2
```

Problem Statement:

Get list of student group whom a teacher has access to(if a teacher has access to all students under a student group then only then that student group is accessible).
**Therefore student group accessible to tid= 11 are sgid=101 and sgid= 201, whereas for tid=22 is sgid=201.**

```
SELECT sg.sgid
FROM   sg
       JOIN sgm
       ON (sg.sgid = sgm.sgid)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t_s_map
       ON (sgm.SID       = t_s_map.SID)
WHERE  t_s_map.tid = 22
GROUP BY sg.sgid
HAVING MAX (NVL(t_s_map.SID, 0)) > 0 AND MIN (NVL(t_s_map.SID, 0)) > 0;
```

Now the above query works fine but it's slow, is there any alternate(faster) way to do it.

Current Version:

```
SELECT sgm.sgid
FROM   sgm           
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t_s_map
       ON (sgm.SID       = t_s_map.SID)
WHERE  t_s_map.tid = 22
GROUP BY sgm.sgid
HAVING MIN (NVL(t_s_map.SID, 0)) > 0;
```

Comment: Have you tried adding indexes to the tables? This could well speed up the query.

Comment: Note that your left join is completely pointless because you are applying a predicate to the table being outer joined to: "where t_s_map.tid = 1234"

Comment: You do not need the `MAX` since if `MIN > 0` then `MAX >= MIN > 0`

Comment: @L30n1d45 is it a homework?

Comment: all id columns are indexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post sample data , so I couldn't try it.
Can you see this query pls?  It should be equivalent of the one you posted above.

Since you used WHERE t_s_map.id the LEFT JOIN is equivalent to a INNER JOIN.

Moreover it seems to me that your HAVING condition are not necessary (SID should always have a value >0.  Am I wrong on this last point?)

```
SELECT DISTINCT sg.sgid
FROM sg
INNER JOIN sgm ON sg.sgid = sgm.sgid
INNER JOIN t_s_map ON sgm.SID= t_s_map.SID
WHERE t_s_map.tid = 1234;
```

**Update:**

As concern "Problem statement" I think your (nor mine above) is what is asked.
Next query could.

```
SELECT TID, C.SGID
FROM t_s_map B
LEFT JOIN SGM C ON B.SID = C.SID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sgid, COUNT(*) AS RC FROM SGM GROUP BY sgid) D ON C.SGID = D.SGID
GROUP BY TID, C.SGID, RC
HAVING COUNT(*) = RC;
```

**Second Update**
I think you could easily find that to obtain only SGID, you can modify above query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.SGID
FROM t_s_map B
LEFT JOIN SGM C ON B.SID = C.SID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sgid, COUNT(*) AS RC FROM SGM GROUP BY sgid) D ON C.SGID = D.SGID
GROUP BY TID, C.SGID, RC
HAVING COUNT(*) = RC;
```

Comment: added sample data

Comment: That is not the requirement: for tid as input i want list of accessible sgid as output.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing a `left join`.  Your `where` clause turns it into an `inner join`.  So, start with:

```
SELECT sg.sgid
FROM sg JOIN
     sgm
     ON sg.sgid = sgm.sgid JOIN
     t_s_map
     ON sgm.SID = t_s_map.SID
WHERE t_s_map.tid = 1234
GROUP BY sg.sgid
HAVING MAX(t_s_map.SID) > 0 AND MIN(COALESCE(t_s_map.SID, 0)) > 0;
```

Next, the `join` to `sg` is not necessary.

```
SELECT sgm.sgid
FROM sgm JOIN
     t_s_map
     ON sgm.SID = t_s_map.SID
WHERE t_s_map.tid = 1234
GROUP BY sgm.sgid
HAVING MAX(t_s_map.SID) > 0 AND MIN(COALESCE(t_s_map.SID, 0)) > 0;
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `t_s_map(tid, sid)` and `sgm(sgid)`.

Comment: There are too many arguments in `MIN(t_s_map.SID, 0)` - you need to remove the `, 0`.

Comment: It's not an inner join.

Comment: @L30n1d45 . . . It may not be an `inner join` when you write it.  It is an `inner join` when it runs and processes the `where` conditions.

Comment: Then how come the results are different.

Comment: @L30n1d45 . . . I just realized that the `MIN()` condition is different from yours.  With `COALESCE()` (the ANSI standard version of `NVL()`), perhaps the filtering will be the asme.

Answer (score 0):

As per order of execution of SQL Queries first From and Joins get executed , Where clause after that. Try to use below query for reducing number of rows from filter. than you can add your group by and having clause accordingly.

```
SELECT sg.sgid
FROM sg
JOIN sgm
ON (sg.sgid = sgm.sgid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select SID from t_s_map
                 where t_s_map.tid = 1234) tmp
on  (sgm.SID = tmp.SID)
```

Comment: Used Sub query in place of t_s_map table with where clause

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to include the `sg` table, the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses effectively turn the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` and you do not need to check the `MAX` value since `MAX >= MIN` and if `MIN > 0` then `MAX >= MIN > 0` and you do not need the `NVL` since both `0 > 0` and `NULL > 0` are not true.

```
SELECT sgm.sgid
FROM   sgm
       INNER JOIN t_s_map
       ON ( sgm.SID = t_s_map.SID )
WHERE  t_s_map.tid = 1234
GROUP BY sgm.sgid
HAVING MIN(t_s_map.SID) > 0;
```